# How to wrap x number of nested items with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I have a list of nested items:

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item A
    <ul>
      <li>Item A1</li>
      <li>Item A2</li>
      <li>Item A3</li>
      <li>Item A4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item B</li>
  <li>Item C</li>
  <li>Item D</li>
  <li>Item E</li>
  <li>Item F</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Item F1</li>
    <li>Item F2</li>
    <li>Item F3</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item G</li>
  <li>Item H</li>
</ul>
```

The issue being I need to wrap every 4 items in a container:

```html
<ul>
  <div>
    <li>Item A
      <ul>
        <li>Item A1</li>
        <li>Item A2</li>
        <li>Item A3</li>
        <li>Item A4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item B</li>
    <li>Item C</li>
    <li>Item D</li>
  </div>
  <div>
    <li>Item E</li>
    <li>Item F</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Item F1</li>
      <li>Item F2</li>
      <li>Item F3</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item G</li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

When I try to do it based on the number of list items it counts the children too. Also, if the last set is less than four I still need to contain it. Every example I found uses a simple list instead of a nested list so their examples don't work.

Comment: You can't have div elements around the list items. A list can only contain list items, no other elements.

Comment: mh.. why you cannot nest a div in a li?!

Comment: yeah... fair point. trying to find a solution around a problem that I can't control. A bit of "grasping at straws" at this point.

Comment: I think what @Guffa is saying divs around an li is invalid HTML (and it is) but divs inside the li is valid XHTML.

Comment: @AlexTape: I didn't say that you can't nest a div in an li, I said that you can't nest a li in a div.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping a li with a div is invalid html. However, you can try this.
give your top ul an id and the use the code below

```
while ($("#test > li").length >0 ){
  $("#test > li").slice(0, 4).wrapAll("<div/>") ;
}
```

Comment: I'm working inside some fairly strict confines so I can't add classes to the ul items. Looking into "splitting list" items right now.